# Compilation of Realtek RTS5229 driver fails

Tags: drivers, compiling, realtek

I'm currently trying to compile the driver for the SD card reader, a Realtek RTS5229, of my new laptop computer. However, when running `make`, I'm presented with the following errors:

```
$ make       # reduced messages to errors
/home/sebastian/UbuntuSetup/Realtek_RTS5229_Linux_Driver_v1.07/rts5229/rtsx.c:266:2: error: unknown field ‘proc_info’ specified in initializer
  .proc_info =   proc_info,
  ^
/home/sebastian/UbuntuSetup/Realtek_RTS5229_Linux_Driver_v1.07/rts5229/rtsx.c:914:22: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rtsx_probe’
 static int __devinit rtsx_probe(struct pci_dev *pci, const struct pci_device_id *pci_id)
                      ^
/home/sebastian/UbuntuSetup/Realtek_RTS5229_Linux_Driver_v1.07/rts5229/rtsx.c:1069:23: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rtsx_remove’
 static void __devexit rtsx_remove(struct pci_dev *pci)
                       ^
/home/sebastian/UbuntuSetup/Realtek_RTS5229_Linux_Driver_v1.07/rts5229/rtsx.c:1094:11: error: ‘rtsx_probe’ undeclared here (not in a function)
  .probe = rtsx_probe,
           ^
/home/sebastian/UbuntuSetup/Realtek_RTS5229_Linux_Driver_v1.07/rts5229/rtsx.c:1095:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘__devexit_p’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  .remove = __devexit_p(rtsx_remove),
  ^
/home/sebastian/UbuntuSetup/Realtek_RTS5229_Linux_Driver_v1.07/rts5229/rtsx.c:1095:24: error: ‘rtsx_remove’ undeclared here (not in a function)
  .remove = __devexit_p(rtsx_remove),
                        ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/home/sebastian/UbuntuSetup/Realtek_RTS5229_Linux_Driver_v1.07/rts5229/rtsx.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/sebastian/UbuntuSetup/Realtek_RTS5229_Linux_Driver_v1.07/rts5229] Error 2
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

The errors occur in [rtsx.c](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/326576/rtsx.c) (uploaded to my Dropbox)

---

Ubuntu Trusty x64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to compile them. They are in the following packages, Install them.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev linux-headers-`uname -r` linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Comment: I've installed those packages, but still no change. `lshw` still tells `UNCLAIMED` and modprobe'ing rts5229 doesn't work either. What do I have to do afer installing those packages?

Comment: Update: After a second reboot it worked. Thank you very much. I didn't even know that `linux-firmware-nonfree` existed.

Comment: Update2: Now it's not working any more. Do I have to add something to `/etc/modules` etc.?

Comment: I removed the "Accepted Answer" as it's not working any more after another reoot-... do you have a fix for that?

Comment: Sorry. Try with reinstalling the driver packages. Better if `--purge autoremove && sudo apt-get install`

Comment: I purged and reinstalled. Then I noticed that it only works when a SD card is plugged during boot. So I added the entries `mmc_block`, `rtsx_pci` and `rtsx_pci_sdmmc` to `/etc/modules` and ran `update-initramfs -u`. However, this didn't have any effect...

Comment: I found a similar problem with Gentoo being solved by rebuilding the kernel with a different configuration. The person changed the following kernel config entries: `CONFIG_HOTPLUG_PCIE=y`, `CONFIG_HOTPLUG_PCI=y` and `CONFIG_HOTPLUG_PCI_ACPI=y`. However, these are already set in my current kernel config. Any ideas? http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-992572.html?sid=f51ed0d719be6d6bc12cfa11282e1ba8

Comment: When inserting the SD card *after* boot, `dmesg` reports `pciehp 0000:00:05.0:pcie04: Card present on Slot(0-2)`, and when removing it, `...Card not present...`. So the SD card gets detected, but no device file is created etc. I'd assume something to be wrong in udev

Comment: Very sorry: I dont know that much details. My friend had the same problem and it was solved after installing above packages. Thats why I published this answer. Isnt it better if it is asked in a separate question?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'll create a seperate question