# SD card reader only works if card is inserted during boot

Tags: drivers, realtek, sd-card

I'm trying to get the Realtek RTS5229 SD Card Reader to run on my newly installed system.

I installed `linux-firmware-nonfree` to get the driver for the RTS5229 SD card reader, according to my [other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/488520/compilation-of-realtek-rts5229-driver-fails/489324) on this topic.

However, the card reader only works if a SD Card is plugged during boot. When I plug it *after* boot, there isn't any device file and the udev monitor doesn't show anything when (un-)plugging the card. Also, `lshw` shows `UNCLAIMED` at the device's entry. I already tried the following:

- Purging and reinstalling `linux-firmware-nonfree`
- Insert `mmc_block`, `rtsx_pci` and `rtsx_pci_sdmmc` into `/etc/modules` and ran `update-initramfs -u`
- Searched for another solution -> [Gentoo forums](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-992572.html?sid=f51ed0d719be6d6bc12cfa11282e1ba8), but suggested kernel config already set
- Read `dmesg | tail` after card was inserted after boot -> `[  626.100472] pciehp 0000:00:05.0:pcie04: Card present on Slot(0-2)`
- Read `udevadm monitor` -> add/remove events fired when plugged at boot time, no events when not.

What is the problem and how can I resolve it? Please ask for further information if needed.

**Edit:** Is there at least the possibility to run `echo "1" > /sys/bus/pci/reload` when a card is inserted (when the kernel posts the "Card is present" message to /var/log/kern.log)

Comment: Is the exact name of the driver `rts5229` (or is it `mmc_block`, rtsx_pci`, `rtsx_pci_sdmmc`, etc...)? Then you could unload it with `sudo modprobe -r rts5229`, put the SD card in, and load it again with `sudo modprobe rts5229`. You can view the driver when it works in `lshw`, or possibly `lspci -v`

Comment: I don't know what the driver name is. I just compared the `lsmod` of both cases and these modules were loaded when the card was plugged on boot. Un- and reloading them doesn't work.

Comment: Can you open `gnome-disks` and check if the card shows up there? If yes, can you select it and try manually mounting there (click on the Play button). If that works I think there is some error or missing line in udisks2 rules which we can try to fix.

Comment: Other thing: did you check if there is a setting in BIOS to enable/disable the card reader (usually there is), and if so then whether it is enabled in BIOS?

Comment: Did you see [this forum discussion](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-7511366.html)? Is the card detected if you insert it and then do `echo "1" > /sys/bus/pci/rescan` ?

Comment: Similarly to @bain, this might be this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/995743)

Comment: the card doesn't show up and there is nothing in the BIOS settings. after executing the command, the card gets detected.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like some people have had better success with the older drivers from [Realtek](http://www.realtek.com/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=25&PFid=25&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#RTS5101/RTS5111/RTS5116/RTS5169).

However, these have compilation problems on newer kernels. Some people have been able to get around by removing the offending symbols in the source files then installing the module (removing/blacklisting the kernel installed module). See [this](http://abhinavgupta2812.wordpress.com/2014/01/28/getting-a-realtek-sd-card-reader-to-work-on-linux-tried-and-tested-on-debian/) and [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2059763&p=13076460#post13076460). Apparently there is also a more recent source of the driver mentioned [here](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=100596) though it has the same compilation problems which can be fixed as above.

This will be somewhat painful to maintain since it has to be recompiled on every kernel upgrade. Someone has created a dkms package [here](https://launchpad.net/~jamesf/+archive/ubuntu/lenovofixes), and though it is for older 12.04 release, it should be possible to pick up the source deb of that and integrate the patch mentioned above in it.

Still I will suggest trying to get it working with the kernel driver first. I had two suggestions before: a) does it show up in gnome-disks, b) is it enabled in BIOS . In any case I think this should be reported in kernel upstream since the kernel driver is supposed to be created from the GPLed Realtek's driver. Perhaps it has something to do with the "rts5229_ids" list in rtsx.c?

Comment: As commented above, a) it only shows up after executing `echo "1" > /sys/bus/pci/rescan`. b) There is no option to enable/disable it, and besides, then it wouldn't work when the card was inserted at boot time, would it?

Comment: Ok I was able to compile and install the driver. However, I don't see any difference to the preinstalled one.